# How to find this Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Q. Find the Linear Transformation $T:V_3\rightarrow V_3$ , such that

$T(0,1,2)=(3,1,2)$

$T(1,1,1)=(2,2,2)$

I tried considering $(0,1,2),(1,1,1)$ as basis, it doesnt seem to work that way. Just need some pointers in the right direction !

Comment: Thanks for the down votes and close recommendations, but some hints would be more helpful. The question is anyway marked as a homework and not some research work.

Comment: I think there are infinitely many such transformations. Generally, to fix a transformation we need three independent images... is there something more to the problem? Could it be that the question is to find "all" $T$ which fit the data given?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook : The question doesn't say anything else. That was my concern as well. Lets say if its about finding all the transformations, how do we approach it ?

Comment: To see how it "works" try $a=1, b=0$ and $a=0, b=1$.

Comment: so ideally this question should have given one more transformation in order to give a fixed result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider,
$$ T(a(0,1,2)+b(1,1,1)) = a(3,1,2)+b(2,2,2) $$
this works, but is not defined on all of $V_3$. However, if $v \notin \text{span} \{ (0,1,2), (1,1,1) \}$ then 
$$ T(a(0,1,2)+b(1,1,1)+cv) = a(3,1,2)+b(2,2,2) $$
still produces the needed transformation on the given points. So, I suppose the question becomes how do you categorize all vectors outside that span?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\v}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$**Some general** (non-direct) **hints**

1. Since the transformation is linear, $T(a\v{u}+b\v{v})= aT(\v{u})+bT(\v{v})$.
2. $(0,1,2)=(0,1,0)+2(0,0,1)$ and $(1,1,1)=(1,0,0)+(0,1,0)+(0,0,1)$
3. Consider the effect of $T$ on the standard basis, $\{\v{i},\v{j},\v{k}\}$.
4. This should lead you to a system of linear equations. The solution of this system gives $T$.

In applying the above to this case, you should not expect to find a unique transformation, as you still have $9$ values to determine, but only $6$ conditions ($3$ from each transformation given).